# Using JSON config file in javascript library

Tags: javascript, almond

I using almond.js to implement my javascript library. I trying to separate config variables from code. I created config.json file, which contains all 'global' variables and defined 'Model' which will injected to other modules:

```
define("Model", [], function () {
    "use strict";

    var model = {
        options: {
        }
    };

    (function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xhr.open('GET', 'Config/config.json', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300)) {
                model.options = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    })();

    return model;
});
```

The problem is, then i define over modules which using my 'Model', the request still not finished and all of 'options' parameters is still `undefined`.
Is any way to implement dependencies that will wait for model initialization or maybe another way to achieve this functionality with almond.js?

Should i replace almond.js by require.js to achieve this functionality? If can, how it will looks like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almond does not support dynamic loading at all, so I doubt this is possible or even makes sense

Comment: Hi Patrick. I can replace almond.js by require.js. It will help me to achieve what i need?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question:
Before the changes my launcher script was:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    require("Core");
})();
```

where "Core" is main module which include all dependencies.

The change: 
I removed static `define("Model", [],function(){...});`

My launcher became:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    (function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xhr.open('GET', 'Config/config.json', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300)) {
                var model = {
                    options: JSON.parse(xhr.response)
                };

                if (define && define.amd) {
                    define("Model", model);
                    require("Core"); 
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    })();
})();
```

Now all model options is parsed from config.json file and ready when i run all dependencies chain.